# Subscript and Superscripts on characters vectors

Tags: r

I wish to have both Subscripts and Superscripts on my character vectors, relative to the X and Y values on a plot.

For example, the X values are the superscript and Y values are the subscript.

Here's an example of what it should look like:
[image]

I have tried pasting superscripts then plotting these, although it hasn't worked out like expected

Code for plot:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Neutron, y = Protons, group = Isotopes)) + geom_point() +geom_line() +geom_label(label = test$Isotopes) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = test$Neutron) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = test$Protons)
> ggplot(test, aes(x=Neutron, y = Protons)) + geom_point() +geom_line() +geom_label(label = test$Isotopes) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = test$Neutron) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = test$Protons)
```

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(Neutron = c(237, 233, 233, 229, 225, 225, 221, 
217, 213, 213, 209, 209, 205), Protons = c(93, 91, 92, 90, 88, 
89, 87, 85, 83, 84, 82, 83, 81), Isotopes = c("Np", "Pa", "U", 
"Th", "Ra", "Ac", "Fr", "At", "Bi", "Po", "Pb", "Bi", "Tl")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sprintf` or `paste` to create the labels, then specify the `label` in `aes` and `parse` it in `geom_label`

```
library(ggplot2)
lbl1 <- with(test, sprintf('%s[%d]^%d', Isotopes, Protons, Neutron))
ggplot(test, aes(x=Neutron, y = Protons, label = lbl1)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_line() +
        geom_label(parse= TRUE) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = test$Neutron) + 
         scale_y_continuous(breaks = test$Protons)
```

-output

[image]